# SKIP kanji search for Linux, usable offline

Tags: linux, open-source, dictionary, japanese

[SKIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodansha_Kanji_Learner%27s_Dictionary#SKIP) is a convenient way to find Japanese kanjis.
It often looks similar to [this](https://kanji.sljfaq.org/skip.html):

[image: SKIP]

Is there a SKIP program for Linux?

Requirements:

- Works offline
- Open source
- Fast to launch and search

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gjiten - I have heard that it supports SKIP, but as I can't understand it myself, I can't verify it.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs: I use Gjiten every day. Some forks of Gjiten can show a kanji's SKIP number, but none has any SKIP search feature unfortunately.